# Google play services location not working as it should

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

Hi I implemented The google play services for location in my application(I'm using almost the same code of the sample from google). And after testing, the application doesn't seem to work as I expect.

If I set the accuracy to  `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` or `PRIORITY_NO_POWER`, The Location simply doesn't fetch anything when I'm not connected to wifi.

And the amount of time the location is fetched is at minimum double than the interval that I set in `mLocationRequest.setInterval()`

Anybody else having this problem ? Or am I missing something here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the problem,

I added only the     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>` but didn't add the 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` (I thought this one was only for GPS) I was wrong.

The  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>` gives the precision on a city block level according to Android documentation.

> Apps that use Location Services must request location permissions.
>   Android has two location permissions: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. The permission you choose controls the accuracy
>   of the current location. **If you request only coarse location
>   permission, Location Services obfuscates the returned location to an
>   accuracy that's roughly equivalent to a city block.**

So in my case on short distances it was always getting the same location.

Adding the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html). The emphasis in bold is mine.

> At the other extreme, if you want negligible power impact, but to
>   still receive location updates when available, then create a location
>   request with setPriority(int) set to PRIORITY_NO_POWER. **With this
>   request your application will not trigger (and therefore will not
>   receive any power blame) any location updates, but will receive
>   locations triggered by other applications.** This would be appropriate
>   for applications that have no firm requirement for location, but can
>   take advantage when available.

For the second part, the PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY. That part doesn't seem to be responding as the documentation describes. I need to look more into it.

> In between these two extremes is a very common use-case, where
>   applications definitely want to receive updates at a specified
>   interval, and can receive them faster when available, but still want a
>   low power impact. These applications should consider
>   PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY combined with a faster
>   setFastestInterval(long) (such as 1 minute) and a slower
>   setInterval(long) (such as 60 minutes). They will only be assigned
>   power blame for the interval set by setInterval(long), but can still
>   receive locations triggered by other applications at a rate up to
>   setFastestInterval(long). This style of request is appropriate for
>   many location aware applications, including background usage. Do be
>   careful to also throttle setFastestInterval(long) if you perform
>   heavy-weight work after receiving an update - such as using the
>   network.

Comment: Thank you for the info about PRIORITY_NO_POWER ,Now it's clear. Concerning the PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, could it be that it completely avoids the use of GPS ?

Comment: I don't know. The documentation doesn't match up with what you're saying. Could it be that your phone only has the location settings for "Wi-Fi & mobile network location" checked, and not the "GPS satellites" checked? What phone are you using by the way?

Comment: It's a galaxy nexus, I have GPS enabled, i'll debug it more these 2 days. it should be something with my code. Thanks a lot for the help